# chrome extensions: gzip css/js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gzip

i am making a chrome app. The js and css have now grown to be quiet large. i have no earlier experience with gzip. But i did some research and found that serving gzip files requires to make some changes to .HTACCESS file. but it is not possible in my app. So can anyone give me a brief description of how to compress files and publish them successfully?

Comment: server? it is a chrome app.. so.. what server?

Comment: local? so gzip won't help -- gzip is for transferring over network, it is decompressed on-the-fly.

Comment: really? so the files served from chrome-extension://asdf url cant be compressed..? damn..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no point in compressing local files, it would just slow things down. All gzips, minifiers and such were made to battle network transfer speed at all costs as it is the bottleneck. For local files simple file read is much faster than read+decompress. For local files compression is used only to save disk space, not to speed things up.

The most you should do is minify your files (Google Closure Compiler, YUICompressor, packer, etc), as it makes files smaller and doesn't cost anything (just need to make sure that it doesn't over-minifying files at a cost of execution speed, I think packer has such option).

Comment: so i should let the files be non gziped? well makes sense so its good enough for me :D but as for minifying, i tried a couple of online sites to minify my js but it increased the file size from 32 kn to 50 kb :O any idea whats happening?

Comment: @Achshar So your js file is 32kb and you are calling it "quite large"?  :) Just leave it as it is, it not worth the effort. I don't know which sites you tried, but those I listed are the most popular solutions (only packer has online interface I think)

Comment: hmm ok lol i think i started worrying about compression prematurely :P but i will try one of those sites.. :D thanks!